# elasticsearch timeout unless i reindex

Tags: elasticsearch

I a running ES 6.1.2 and I have about 2,000 records that are indexed.  Everything works great if I reindex, but throughout the day, things seem to decay and eventually, when submitting a search, it just times out.  If I reindex, everything works great.  Is there a troubleshooting recipe I can take a look at, or is this a known issue with this version? Any other pointers?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: What do you see in hot threads information (`GET /_nodes/hot_threads`) when you are experiencing timeouts? What is your elasticsearch configuration (how many nodes, RAM per node etc)?

Comment: upgrading to 7.3 fixed the problem.